# Bot with TelegramApi javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: kotlin, telegram-bot, sslhandshakeexception, telegram-webhook, telegram-api

Hi I'm building a telegram bot that works, but whenever I try it on my laptop company it throws me this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I don't think the problem is related to jdk or jre or something like that. I believe that my laptop company is configured and somehow is blocking the access to telegram api or something like that since I see cisco stuff, vpn and things that I can't do on this laptop that in a normal laptop I could do. So yeah this is capped.

I found this [post](https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api/issues/160), and he solved it (I don't know how that example works since I haven't tested it yet) and then 1 year later he came back saying that it doesn't work anymore for him, here's the other [post](https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api/issues/207).

I'm using this [telegram-bot in Kotlin](https://github.com/kotlin-telegram-bot/kotlin-telegram-bot) which doesn't have a way to set the OkHttpClient, but it has webhook and I believe that is related to that but maybe I'm wrong.

Is there any way to fix this and keep building this telegram bot on my laptop company?

Comment: facing the same problem here. did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Nope, I gave up :( @jndp